# Relaying mail through postfix with SASL

Tags: postfix, sasl

I'd like to relay mail from my laptop through my server. I've successfully configured postfix and SASL, and I can `AUTH` successfully using telnet.

```
dhcp-241:~ jgorset$ telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying 85.25.124.196...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO mail.example.com
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN ***********************
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
MAIL FROM: <user@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <bob@gmail.com>
554 5.7.1 <bob@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

As demonstrated above, I'm being denied relay through my postfix server even though I've authenticated and configured postfix to allow authenticated clients to relay mail.

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
# SMTP authentication
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject, permit_sasl_authenticated
```

Am I being rejected because the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` option is set to `reject`, even though is specifically states to `permit_sasl_authenticated`? I was under the impression that the latter would override the former, seeing that you are required to enter either `reject`, `defer`, `defer_if_permit` or `reject_unauth_destination` with this option.

---

**Update**: Turns out this also happens if I telnet from localhost. If I comment out the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` line, I can send mail to anyone (though only from localhost). I'd like to do so from any computer that authenticates using SASL. How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smtpd_receipient_restrictions are matched from left-to-right, first match wins.

You want `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject`

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much; I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for hours.

Answer (score 2):

smtp_recipient_restrictions are evaluated in order.

You probably want something that at least starts like this:

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
                        permit_sasl_authenticated
                        permit_mynetworks

And then proceed to either reject all (if you are only sending mail and never receiving mail on this server) or reject things that look like spam - check out the postfix docs for UCE to get a good starting point.

Comment: This will create an open relay (no match at end of list = permit)

Comment: Sorry - meant to say "And then proceed to" -- perhaps the paragraph after the line wasn't clear.